# Difference between IRS and phased array/reflectarray

Tags: antenna, antenna-array

just wondering out of curiosity the difference between intelligent reflecting surface (IRS) and more traditional antenna arrays such as phased array and reflectarray?

From the surface it looks a whole lot similar but perhaps from different angles (IRS - more system/optimization focused and antenna arrays are more studied as an independent component), but was wondering if I was missing the key concepts/ other differences behind IRS.

Answer (score 2):

Phased arrays have a number of transmitters/receivers in parallel that vary the phase in order to digitally form a lens.  This lets the transmitters/receivers adjust its gain in each direction digitally.  IRS are (usually) passive devices that vary how an incoming signal (possibly from a phased array, MIMO device, etc) reflects in/out of a space.  They're conceptually similar, and a reflective IRS with a directional antenna pointed directly at it would effectively be a phased array.

For more information, the introduction of this paper compares IRS to MIMO and related technologies:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04789.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree that IRS are more similar to reflectarrays but thought phased array would be more known, would you say that IRS and reflectarrays are essentially the same?

Comment: Why can’t you search?

Comment: Not quite.  Phase arrays do not have to have a "number of transmitters in parallel".  Receive only phase arrays, for example may only have a receive chain behind each individual element.  And passive phase arrays only have a single transmitter and a single receiver (well, maybe more, as you need a separate receive chain for SUM, Delta AZ, and Delta EL) channels from the antenna, and possible a fourth for the guard).  The best you can say is that a phase array has a number of phase shifters in parallel, one phase shifter for each element (assuming a single beam system).

Comment: That's what makes it a phase array - the phase shifters; not the transmitters or receivers.

Comment: @SteveSh Made it more general to encompass Rx, Tx.   Technically a phased array doesn't even need antenna, since not all phased arrays use electromagnetic fields.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " phased array doesn't even need antenna".  In in this context, a "phased array" IS a type of antenna.

Comment: @SteveSh  Laser/sonar phased arrays do not use antenna.

Comment: But that's not what OP was referring to.  And you still don't need "transmitters/receivers in parallel" to vary the phase.

Comment: @SteveSh  It sounded like you were suggesting a more generalized answer than the typical RF case of an array of antenna.  If you have a more specific suggestion, please let me know.  For what it is worth, in my field, a phased array is always composed specifically of parallel transmitters. An external phase modulator array would no longer be considered a phased array (although mathematically it is the same thing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116447/discussion-between-stevesh-and-user1850479).